# solving the simplest PDE (non trivial): $\Delta u(x,t) = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

(Also the PDE can be written like $\partial_{xx}u+\partial_{tt}u = 0$)

Of course for unambiguity this needs some condition:

$\bullet\quad u(0,t) = 0, \quad u(1,t) = 0$

$\bullet \quad u(x,0) = 0 \quad u(x,1) = 1$

Finding the function should be fairly easy due to the linearity:

it alludes the function $u$ is separable: $u(x,t) = X(x)\cdot T(t)$

> Respectively for the PDE:  $$\begin{align} &\partial_{xx}  X(x)\,T(t) +
>  X(x)\,\partial_{tt} T(t) \quad \Leftrightarrow
>  \quad\dfrac{\partial_{xx}X(x)}{X(x)} = \dfrac{\partial_{tt}T(t)}{T(t)}
>  \end{align}$$
>
> Both sides should equal a constant:
>
> $$\begin{array}{cc} &\dfrac{\partial_{xx}X(x)}{X(x)} = \lambda\\\\
>  &\dfrac{\partial_{tt}T(t)}{T(t)} = \lambda \end{array}$$
>
> It turns out, only $\lambda = -\lambda$ fulfils the starting
> conditions. For elegancy one choses $\lambda = -\lambda^2$
>
> After all 2 ODE are to be solved:
>
> $$\begin{array}{cc} &\partial_{xx}X(x)+\lambda^2\,X(x) = 0 &\quad
> \Rightarrow X(x) = A\,\cos(\lambda\,x)+B\,\sin(\lambda\,x)\\\\
>  &\partial_{tt}T(t)+\lambda^2\,T(t) = 0 &\quad \Rightarrow T(t) =
>  C_1\,\cos(\lambda\,t)+C_2\,\sin(\lambda\,t) \end{array}$$
>
> This yields the total solution: $$\displaystyle{u(x,t) =
>  \left(A\,\cos(\lambda\,x)+B\,\sin(\lambda\,x)\right)\, 
>  \left(C_1\,\cos(\lambda\,t)+C_2\,\sin(\lambda\,t)\right)}$$
>
> Now using starting Condition:
>
> How do I actually use these?
>
> $\begin{array}{ccc} &\bullet &X(0) =
>  A\,\cos(\lambda\,0)+B\,\sin(\lambda\,0) = 0 &\Rightarrow A = 0\\\\ & &
>  X(1) = A\,\cos(\lambda\,1)+B\,\sin(\lambda\,1) = 0 &\Rightarrow
>  \lambda = n\,\pi \end{array}$
>
> so?
>
> It seems like there are endless discrete solution, since $\lambda  =
>  n\,\pi \quad n \in \mathbb{N}$
>
> The solution has to be the sum of all of them:
>
> $u(x,t) = \displaystyle{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} B\,\sin(\lambda\,x)\,\left(C_1\,\cos(\lambda\,t)+C_2\,\sin(\lambda\,t)\right)}$
>
> at this point let's call $B\,C_1 = a_n$ and $B\,C_2 = b_n$:
>
> $u(x,t) = \displaystyle{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
>  \sin(\lambda\,x)\,\left(a_n\,\cos(\lambda\,t)+b_n\,\sin(\lambda\,t)\right)}$
>
> Now using the other starting conditions:
>
> $\begin{array}{ccc} &\bullet \quad &u(x,0) =  \displaystyle{\sum_{n =
>  1}^{\infty}
>  \sin(\lambda\,x)\,\left(a_n\,\cos(\lambda\,0)+b_n\,\sin(\lambda\,0)\right)
>  = 0} &\Rightarrow a_n = 0 ?\\\\ & &u(x,1) = \displaystyle{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
>  \sin(\lambda\,x)\,\left(a_n\,\cos(\lambda\,1)+b_n\,\sin(\lambda\,1)\right)
>  = 1} &\Rightarrow b_n = 0 ?  \end{array}$
>
> For the solution process I kept myself inspired by the solution of the
> wave equation, but since the starting conditions are different I can't
> really transfer it all. I don't even know it is relatable at all

---

**Addendum**

Looked like I was caught by a disastrous sign error: going to be:

$$\begin{align} \dfrac{\partial_{xx}X(x)}{X(x)} = \color{red}{{-}}\dfrac{\partial_{tt}Y(y)}{Y(y)}
 \end{align}$$

hence the solutions:

$$\begin{array}{cc} &\partial_{xx}X(x)+\lambda^2\,X(x) = 0 &\quad
\Rightarrow X(x) = A\,\cos(\lambda\,x)+B\,\sin(\lambda\,x)\\\\
 &\partial_{tt}Y(y)\color{red}{{-}}\lambda^2\,Y(y) = 0 &\quad \Rightarrow Y(y) =
 C_1\,\cosh(\lambda\,t)+C_2\,\sinh(\lambda\,t) \end{array}$$

luckily the constant $\lambda$ is still the same so the solution can be straight written as sum:

$$u(x,t) = \displaystyle{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
 \sin(\lambda_n\,x)\,\left(a_n\,\cosh\lambda_n\,t)+b_n\,\sinh(\lambda_n\,t)\right)}$$

Now, again trying to use starting condition:

$\begin{array}{ccc} &\bullet \quad &u(x,0) =  \displaystyle{\sum_{n =
 1}^{\infty}
 \sin(\lambda_n\,x)\,\left(a_n\,\cosh(\lambda_n\,0)+b_n\,\sinh(\lambda_n\,0)\right)
 = 0} &\Rightarrow a_n = 0 \\\\ & &u(x,1) = \displaystyle{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
 \sin(\lambda\,x)\,\left(a_n\,\cosh(\lambda_n\,1)+b_n\,\sinh(\lambda_n\,1)\right)
 = 1} &\Rightarrow b_n = ?  \end{array}$

Here I'm tripping once more.

Normally for determing coefficients one multiplies by $\sin(m\,\pi\,x)$ and integrates $[0, 1]$.

Even if $a_n = 0$ it's still heavy:

$$\displaystyle{\sum_{n= 1}^{\infty}b_n\,\int_{0}^{1}\sin(n\,\pi\,x)\,\sinh(\lambda_n\,1)\cdot \sin(m\,\pi\,x)\,\mathrm{dx} = \int_{0}^{1}1 \cdot\sin(m\,\pi\,x)}\,\mathrm{dx}$$

The difficulty consists of evaluation that one big integral.

If you had assumed $\sinh(\lambda_n\,1)$ with $\lambda_n = \pi\,n$ depends on x, like I did this would be pretty awkward. But since it's a constant just draw it out:

$$\begin{array}{cc}\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n\,\sinh(n\,\pi\,1)\,\int_{0}^{1}\sin(n\,\pi\,x)\,\cdot \sin(m\,\pi\,x)\,\mathrm{dx} = \frac{1}{2}\,b_n\,\sinh(n\,\pi\, 1)\,\delta_{n\,m}}\\\\
\text{Now bringing this to the other side (and assuming $n = m$ hence $\delta_{n\,m} = 1$)}:\\\\
\displaystyle{b_n =}
\displaystyle{\dfrac{2}{\sinh(n\,\pi\,1)}\,}\int_{0}^{1}1 \cdot\sin(n\,\pi\,x)\,\mathrm{dx} = \dfrac{2}{\sinh(n\,\pi\,1)}\,\left(\dfrac{1-\cos(n\,\pi)}{n\,\pi}\right)
\end{array}$$

With the predetermined solution:

$$u(x,y) = \displaystyle{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
 \sin(n\,\pi\,x)\,\left(b_n\,\sinh(n\,\pi\,y)\right)} \quad \mathrm{\vert right?}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't use the wave equation $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$ as a source of intuition for the Laplace equation $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$, since they behave completely differently. So let me use the letter $y$ instead of $t$ (and $Y$ instead of $T$).

The main problem with your attempt is that you have a sign error when you're separating the variables; it should be $X_{xx}/X = - Y_{yy}/Y$, so the ODEs for $X$ and for $Y$ are not the same.

A set of separated solutions which satisfy the three boundary conditions where $u=0$ is
$$
u_n(x,y) = \sin(n \pi x) \sinh(n \pi y)
,
$$
so you should be able to finish by determining the constants $c_n$ such that the Fourier sine series
$$
u(x,y)
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n u_n(x,t)
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n \sinh(n \pi y) \sin(n \pi x)
$$
satisfies the remaining boundary condition $u(x,1)=1$ for $0<x<1$.

Comment: Yea, thinking about this tonight I already knew I messed up with the signs. I'll retry.

Comment: May you look at my solutions again? Still in the clutch

Comment: It's looking better now. But in your sums, $\lambda$ should be $\lambda_n = n \pi$. And if you multiply by $\sin(m \pi x)$ and integrate over $[0,1]$ (not $[-\pi,\pi]$!), then because of orthogonality only the $m$th term contributes, so you get $$a_m \sinh(m \pi) \int_0^1 \sin^2 (m \pi x) \, dx = \int_0^1 \sin(m \pi x) \, dx$$ with just one term on the left-hand side, not a sum.

Comment: Right, integrating from $[-\pi, \pi]$ is foolish, since it's already in there. However here I'm integrating from $[-1, 1]$ to avoid a tiny $1/2$. Furthermore calling it $n$ or $m$ is off importance seeing as how both are identical. All your other useful hints are incorporated in the solution now. It should be sealed?

Comment: Yes, except that you have $b_n=0$ for all $n$, since the integrand is an odd function... You really need to integrate over $[0,1]$, not $[-1,1]$, and to get the final answer you should compute that integral explicitly. And of course it doesn't matter whether you call it $m$ or $n$, as long as you don't write $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ where it should be just $a_n$ (or $a_m$).

Comment: Alright, if I haven't miscalculated the integral, it should be fixed now. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Just one more detail: it should be $\frac{1-\cos(n \pi)}{n \pi}$, not $\frac{1}{n \pi}-\cos(n \pi)$.